# Why does javafx-maven-plugin:jlink cause a java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException?

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, javafx, jlink

I am trying to use `jlink` as part of the `javafx-maven-plugin` plugin to create a runtime image with AdoptOpenJDK 15. For some reason I end up getting the following error during the `jlink` goal:

```
Error: java.io.UncheckedIOException: java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: ...\target\image\bin\javaw.exe
```

`javafx:run`, however, works fine.

*Note: The path to the project has been omitted from the error message.*

Comment: Perhaps your antivirus is blocking the creation of executable files?

Comment: That was indeed the reason. I'd like to mark your comment as the answer if you'd like to post it as an answer instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some antiviruses can block the creation of executable files. Check if this is the case and configure your antivirus to exclude `...\target\image\bin\javaw.exe` from being checked, or to trust the `jlink` process to write whatever it wants.